# Explain Arrow's Impossibility Theorem

Tags: proof-explanation

Wikipedia claims for the [proof](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arrow%27s_impossibility_theorem#Proof_by_the_pivotal_voter) of [Arrow's Impossibility Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arrow%27s_impossibility_theorem) that when

- Every voter in segment one ranks B above C and C above A.
- Pivotal voter ranks B above A and A above C.
- Every voter in segment two ranks A above B and B above C.

(B and C may switch for segments one and two but not pivot)

> by IIA the societal outcome must rank A above C, as in the previous case

Why is this true?

Comment: The pivotal voter and segment two both rank A above C (using transitivity for segment two).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The given profile is defined such that A beats B, but if the pivotal voter switches their rank, now B beats A. Since A beats B in this profile and B beats C in the profile by unanimity, A must beat C by transitivity.

In the modified profile, the only thing that changes is where the voters rank B relative to A. By independence of irrelevant alternatives, this can't change the relative ranking of A and C. So A must still beat C in the modified profile.